# Resultado while PHP

Tags: php, while

Olá.

O while que criei é responsável por adicionar várias fotos, porém, quando as fotos são adicionadas elas acabam uma em baixo da outra. Existe algum método para que as fotos saiam uma ao lado da outra?

Comment: Sim, troque os `<tr>` por `<td>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar as imagens dentro de uma div e alinhar essa div, desse jeito.

**No html**

```
<div class="imagem"><img src="imagem-passada-no-while" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="imagem-passada-no-while" /></div>
```

**E no css**

```
.imagem{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Ou se você preferir pode colocar dentro de uma `<ul></ul>` ou `<table></table>`